# Error: cannot read as File when loading model

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I think I am making a novice mistake but am having trouble figuring out what is going wrong.

Error:

`C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing>node classify rlc.jpg
(node:38620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cannot read as File: "model.json"
    at readFile (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\filereader\FileReader.js:266:15)
    at FileReader.self.readAsText (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\filereader\FileReader.js:295:7)
    at C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\io\browser_files.js:226:36
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at BrowserFiles.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\io\browser_files.js:159:39)
    at step (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\io\browser_files.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\io\browser_files.js:29:53)
    at C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\io\browser_files.js:23:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\io\browser_files.js:19:12)
(node:38620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:38620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future,
promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Code:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const tmImage = require('@teachablemachine/image');
const fs = require('fs');
global.FileReader = require('filereader');
const uploadModel =  "model.json"
const uploadWeights = "weights.bin"
const uploadMetadata = "metadata.json"

const readImage = path => {
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
    const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
    return tfimage;
}

const imageClassification = async path => {
    const image = readImage(path);
    const model = await tmImage.loadFromFiles(uploadModel,uploadWeights,uploadMetadata);
    const predictions = await model.predict(image);
    console.log('Classification Results:', predictions);
}

if (process.argv.length !== 3) throw new Error('Incorrect arguments: node classify.js <IMAGE_FILE>');

imageClassification(process.argv[2]);
```

File Structure:

```
/Testing
  /node_modules
  classify.js
  metadata.json
  model.json
  package-lock.json
  rlc.jpg
  weights.bin
```

Background: Trying to take what I have learned deploying image classifying model built in teachable machine with native javascript and adapt it to node js. I am a novice and am tripping over environment differences between node and the browser which all the tutorials I am following are based on.

Tutorials I am following:

- https://becominghuman.ai/image-classification-machine-learning-in-node-js-with-tensorflow-js-dd8e20ba5024
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teachablemachine/image
- http://jamesthom.as/blog/2018/08/07/machine-learning-in-node-dot-js-with-tensorflow-dot-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library expects File in `loadFromFiles` function, [documentation in github](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/blob/f102c2d0a47c2a5fac3bfeb18c58b6a469ba6012/libraries/pose/README.md#loading-the-model---browser-files).
File is [browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) that you cannot use in node by default.
So you need to somehow polyfill that in node environment, check out these libraries 
[node-fetch/fetch-blob](https://github.com/node-fetch/fetch-blob)
[node-file-api/file-api](https://github.com/node-file-api/file-api)

Example usage with `file-api`:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const FileAPI = require('file-api');

const uploadModel =  "model.json"
const uploadModelPath = path.join(process.cwd(), uploadModel);

// polyfill
Object.keys(FileApi).forEach(key => { 
    process[key] = FileApi[key];
})

const uploadModelFile = new File({ 
  buffer: fs.readFileSync(uploadModelPath)
});
```

This library is pretty old though and it might not work, you can try search other polyfill libraries or write yours.
You can see how file is read in [tensor flow source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/81225adc2fcf6fcf633b4119e4b89a3bf55be824/tfjs-core/src/io/browser_files.ts#L138) or you can fork and add possibility to work with node files.

Comment: Working through your solution with file-api. Getting this error: C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\File\File.js:35
      throw new Error("No name");
      ^

Error: No name
    at new File (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\node_modules\←[4mFile←[24m\File.js:35:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Awesome\Google Drive\Source\Programming\JS\Testing\classify.js:24:25)". Going to keep digging thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: You need to specify name for the File like `name: "abc-song.txt"`. You can see source code of libraries in node_moduels, I've used to understand problems by reading source code of libraries.

Comment: Figured that out, rolled back mime to a previous version to solve another problem, seems to be executing now but function "processMetaData" in the @teachablemachine module is throwing an error for invalid metada provided. The investigation continues, thanks again.